# Inform participants in a moved question

Tags: feature-request, migration, notifications

Currently, if a question is moved to another site, no notification is given to the participants. If they do not frequent the destination site, they may never find out, and may think their question was just deleted. It would be nice if all participants in a question (questioner, answerers, and commenters) would be informed when the question is moved.

Also, informing them of the superuser.com password at the time as well would be helpful while superuser.com is still in beta - otherwise they may not be able to read the answer to their question :)

Comment: (note that the **question** stays intact; this mainly affects answers)

Comment: The question stays intact, but can the creator of the question find it easily after it's moved?  And if they're relying on the envelope icon notification, will they ever find out?

Answer (score 4):

There's still no indication when a *normal* question changes for the participants. I feel that this feature is far more valuable to have first, because it is more applicable in the general case. Once/if participants are notified about changes in regular questions, it would be a somewhat trivial process to extend the updates to include cases where posts are moved.

Comment: Yes, notifications for edits to questions one has responded to and answers to one's own questions would be very helpful as well.